# How to use error in Laravel 7 in program?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

[image: Error Image In Laravel]

I want use that error in my code, ex.

```
if(Not Found In Database) then
show alert"Data Not Found In Database"
```

How to make that error include to my variabel?

*Note: I'm using Laravel-7

Comment: These errors are only displayed in debug mode. They will not be visible in production. You can still display errors, thanks to the doc : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors

Comment: hmm, i want use that error to my another code. Because i want to decide the action if the file in server is not found or found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
throw new \Exception("error");
```

---

Edit, adding function for check exist file by use `curl`

```
function checkUrlExistFile($url): bool {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_exec($ch);
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($ch);
  if($info == '200') return true;
  return false;
}
```

And Example

```
if (!checkUrlExistFile($url)) {
  throw new \Exception("error");
}
```

Comment: can u explain me? i must write on where and the meaning of code.

Comment: if(Not Found In Database) {
   throw new \Exception("error");
}

Comment: but throw new Exception not work in product environment, you should write a error page

Comment: can i get `Not Found In Database` variabel in error exception laravel?

Comment: Example: 
$user = User::query()->where(['id' => $id])->first();
if (empty($user)) {
  throw new \Exception("error");
}

Comment: um, ur variable can i use if i have database permission. I just have link for file, that file can i download with link. I dont know how to check that link is valid or not. have a solution?

Comment: it's my code
`$id = $request->id;
 $url = 'https://image.com/'.$id.'.jpg';
 $image = $id.'.jpg';
 $contents = file_put_contents($image, file_get_contents($url));`

and i can download the file if the data is found, if the data not found, the error page show on display.

Comment: `function checkUrlExistFile($url): bool
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if($info == '200') return true;
    return false;
}` you can use this function

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: thanks a lot it's successfull for me, but the answers in comment. i cannt validate successfull, can yo edit your answer? maybe others can learn with that answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First check you have record or not:

```
$data = model::all();
if($data == NULL) {
  echo "<script>alert('data not found')</script>"
}
```

Comment: this code should write on controller or where?, and i dont understand about `model::all()` can u explain to me?

Comment: in controller first you should learn basic of laravel..